# Magento - add Category Tree in custom extension

Tags: magento-1.8

i am trying to create a block for magento category tree in admin panel, till now whatever i have tried seems to fail. i have reffered this

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/231274/P0/

as tutorial but was not able to built, any one with suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Try Marius Extenion http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator.html

Comment: @KeyulShah dude it gaved me 404

Comment: https://github.com/tzyganu/moduleCreator

Comment: okay will check if it works

Comment: yes Its working very fine.

Comment: @KeyulShah no clue how to work around with the module creator. its so confusing

Comment: can you please add some more details what you actually want with snap

Comment: on manage product page i have created 1 popup, in that popup i want to display the category tree which is present in one of the product edit tab.